# NVL Column and NULL

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have rows as shown below

```
ProductId   ProductName      ProductDesc      ProductLoc
101         Camel             Pencil           B-10
102         Parker            Pen              
103         Mirado            Pen              C-10
```

When I execute the following SQL query

```
SELECT *
  FROM tablename
 WHERE productloc = NVL ('', productloc)
```

It gives me the 1st and 3rd row, what I would like to achieve is if productloc is null in where condition of the SQL, then I should get all three rows.

How can I get the desired output.

Comment: hmm..You are comparing productloc with productloc from the same table..Why? If you remove the where statement you will get all rows..

Comment: Keep nvl both sides.

Comment: `NVL ('', productloc)` returns always `productloc` as `''` is equal to `null` in Oracle

Comment: Please share expected final results. if val is null and if val is not null..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select * from tablename;`

Is what you need in that case because your where gives no effect. You compare column with itself.

If you want to filter and include nulls you can do (but probably replace one `productloc` with some value:

`select * from tablename where productloc = productloc or productloc is null;`

Or:

`select * from tablename where nvl(productloc, 'SOME_UNIQUE_VAL') = nvl(productloc, 'SOME_UNIQUE_VAL');`

and also replace one of `productloc` by some value.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like :

```
SELECT *
  FROM tablename
 WHERE nvl(productloc,'zzz') = (case when productloc is null then 'zzz' else productloc end )
```

Here zzz is some dummy value, which otherwise should not be present as value in particular column.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose three different solutions:

If you want all rows (with `productloc` null and valued) you can write the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
```

Without `WHERE` clause.

If you want extract all rows with `productloc` has a specified value or is null, so you can write the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE productloc IS NULL OR productloc = YOURVARIABLE
```

or (the last, without use `OR` condition)

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE NVL(productloc, YOURVARIABLE) = YOURVARIABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using Oracle. In Oracle "NULL" is not a value and because of it any compare function will return false.

I recomend:

```
SELECT *  
  FROM tablename  
 WHERE (productloc = productloc OR productloc IS NULL)
```

Hope it helps,
Sérgio